# .htaccess - Rewrite wildcard for a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect anything that comes in on:

```
http://example.com/api/ /* e.g. http://example.com/api/anything */
```

to:

```
http://localhost:3002/api/ /* e.g. http://localhost:3002/api/anything */
```

Here's what I'm trying but fails:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^api/ http://localhost:3002/api/ [R=301,L]
```

I know I could do routes individually e.g.

```
Redirect 301 /api/thisaddress http://localhost:3002/api/thisaddress
```

But would rather have a wildcard... is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE**

As the web page is a single page app, I currently already have in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: This sounds like you’re trying so hard to make it simple that you’re making it complicated. Are you trying to run two different apps (frontend & backend) in the same directory and same virtual host?

Comment: @Hayden No, multiple node sites on the same server, hence the port issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^api/ http://localhost:3002%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` represents original URI starting with `/api/...`

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
RewriteRule ^api/.*$ http://localhost:3002/$0 [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: The `R=301` and the `L` flag together do not really make sense, do they?

Comment: Actually I have noted in one test case that `L` is still needed even with `R=3xx`. I will try to reproduce that.

Comment: Not working for me, I've updated the question which i think is probably important

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Place this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line and make sure to completely clear your browser cache.